Middleware order not respected ASP.NET Web API
So i 'm using two custom middlewares . One that validates the JWT Token on every request where it needs to be validated , and the one for the /admin routes . The problem is , even tho i specified the order in my Program.cs and the admin middleware is after the jwtTokenmiddleware , the admin one is executed first . Why is that ?
This is my code (relevant pieces): Program.cs
    /* rest of the code*/
builder.Services.AddTransient<JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<AdminMiddleware>();
    /* 
    code
    ...
    ...
    */
app.UseMiddleware<JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory>();
app.UseMiddleware<AdminMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
/* end */

And these are my middlewares: The JWTTokenMiddleware:
using E_Commerce_BackEnd.Services.Helpers.AWS_Secret;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.MIddleware;

public class JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory> _logger;
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;

    public JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory(ILogger<JwtTokenMiddlewareFactory> logger, ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

            // Check if the request path is for Google authentication and bypass JWT validation
            var path = context.Request.Path;
            if (path.StartsWithSegments("/signin-google") || 
                path.StartsWithSegments("/google-response"))
            {
                await next(context);
                return;
            }

            

            // Check if endpoint allows anonymous access
            if (endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<AllowAnonymousAttribute>() != null)
            {
                await next(context);
                return;
            }
            
            
            if (context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("JWTToken", out var token) &&
                context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("userLoggedIn", out var isLoggedIn))
            {
                
                
                var principalUser = await _tokenService.TokenValidation(token);
                

                if (principalUser != null && isLoggedIn == "1")
                {
                    context.User = principalUser;
                    _logger.LogInformation("User successfully set.");
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Invalid JWT Token");
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid JWT Token");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Missing JWT Token");
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Missing JWT Token");
                return;
            }

            await next(context);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationFailureException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Authentication failure: Access was denied by the resource owner or by the remote server.");
            context.Response.Redirect("http://localhost:8080/home");
        }
    }
}

and the Admin one :
namespace E_Commerce_BackEnd.MIddleware;

public class AdminMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<AdminMiddleware> _logger;

    public AdminMiddleware(ILogger<AdminMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Executin admin middleware");
            
            var path = context.Request.Path;
            _logger.LogInformation(path);

            
            bool isLoggedInBool = context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("userLoggedIn", out var isLoggedInString);
            

            if (path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"))
            {
                var isAdmin = false;
                
                if (path.StartsWithSegments("/admin/login"))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Entering admin/login endpoint");

                    if (isLoggedInBool && isLoggedInString == "1" && context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("admin", out var adminLogInCheck))
                    {
                        if (adminLogInCheck == "1")
                        {
                            isAdmin = true;
                            await next(context);
                            return;
                        }
                    
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                        _logger.LogWarning($"Non-admin tried to acces -> {path}");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not allowed here!");
                    }
                }
                
              
                if (isLoggedInBool && isLoggedInString == "1" && context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("admin", out var admin))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Entering /admin/* endpoint");
                    bool adminIsLoggedIn =
                        context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("adminLoggedIn", out var adminLoggedInString);
                    if (admin == "1" && adminIsLoggedIn && adminLoggedInString == "1" )
                    {
                        isAdmin = true;
                        await next(context);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    _logger.LogWarning($"Non-admin tried to acces/ Or invalid validation for the  adminLoggedIn cookie -> {path}");
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not allowed here!");
                    return;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    if (!isLoggedInBool)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("User is not logged in (middleware)");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("User is not logged in");
                        return;
                    }else if (isLoggedInBool && !isAdmin)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning($"Admin cookie not present! Path that was tried -> {path}");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Admin cookie not present");
                        return;
                    }
                    
                }

                await next(context);
       
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in the admin middleware");
            _logger.LogInformation(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        
    }
}

And when i try to log in normally as a Client , not admin , i get this logs
// rest of the logs above 
// relevant ones only
info: E_Commerce_BackEnd.MIddleware.AdminMiddleware[0]
      Executin admin middleware
info: E_Commerce_BackEnd.MIddleware.AdminMiddleware[0]
      /api/user/login

The catch is , if i remove the admin middleware from the request pipeline , everything works perfectly , the Log in works , a JWT Token is assigned to the user , everything is good . But when i register and use the admin middleware , everything stops working ( no jwt token is assigned , nothing). What to do here ?

I believe that the JWTTokenMiddleware is being called first, you can confirm that by adding a similar log at the start of it:
_logger.LogInformation("Executing JWTToken middleware");

The problem with the Admin one, might be because you only call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline if the path starts with '/admin'. So if you end-up in this middleware with a route that does not starts with '/admin' the process will not continue.
So try changing this:
if (path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"))
{
    // Code removed for simplicity

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
    await next(context);
}

To this:
if (path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"))
{
    // Code removed for simplicity
}

// Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
await next(context);

Microsoft has a great documentation about this subject here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Such a simple mistake and i could not see it . i have been trying to modify the code so much that i forgot that that await next was in the if ! Thank you !!!!
